# How can I find unread emails in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

According to Gmail, I've got one unread email in my inbox.

How do I find it without browsing through the entire inbox?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Search for;

> label:unread

OR

> is:unread

in your Gmail search box.

Other Gmail search operators can be found here;

http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=7190

Hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative, you may want to try this in your Gmail search box:

```
in:inbox is:unread
```

Comment: The OP is indeed mentioning the inbox, +1.

Comment: I've been there before- several times and forgot the term. Gmail is still my favorite. :-)

Answer (score 2):

To solve this problem permanently, you can also install "Priority Inbox" from Google Labs (click on the little beaker icon next to your email address in the top right of the page).

Once configured, it will always display all your unread emails **at the top of the list!**

Answer (score 2):

If you do this search repeatedly or generally appreciate brevity, you can use **"l:unread"** or even **"l:^u"** instead of **"is:unread"** (or **"label:unread"**).

Of course, you can combine the quest for unread messages with others:

`"l:^u from:tim"` finds all unread messages from "tim",
`"l:^u l:^t"` finds all unread starred mail,
`"l:^u l:^k subject:hi"` finds all unread messages with "hi" in the subject that are in the Trash.

Answer (score 1):

Gmail now has an option to display unread messages before anything else. There are several "[Index Styles](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/18522?hl=en)" you can use, but I've found this the most helpful for managing my inbox.

Just click the Gear to select **Settings** and view the **Inbox** tab. Choose **Unread first** from the dropdown.

[image: Gmail unread first inbox]